# Ubuntu 19.04 Apache2 local host connection blocked

Tags: networking, apache2, firewall

i try to access my local host through my browser its say `connection blocked`

**note : all firewalls are open for Apache2, MySQL server....**

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

result is

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2019-04-29 16:01:46 +0530; 7min ago
     Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
  Process: 1175 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1244 (apache2)
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 27.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─1244 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1467 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1468 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1469 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1470 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─1471 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─4675 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Apr 29 16:01:36 ghost1 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 29 16:01:46 ghost1 apachectl[1175]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/neeko] does not exist
Apr 29 16:01:46 ghost1 apachectl[1175]: AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/YouPHPTube-master] does not exist
Apr 29 16:01:46 ghost1 apachectl[1175]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using ::1. Set 
Apr 29 16:01:46 ghost1 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
lines 1-22/22 (END)
```

its running perfect **TCP/UDP 80 8080 443** and some other ports are open 
earlier its working fine  after  `sudo apt-get update and upgrade`  iam facing this issues  i restart my PC as well its not working how can i fix this?

Comment: Fix your `sites-available` config files. There are two DocumentRoot statements pointing to non-existent directories.

Comment: i have 3 conf and its enabled there no issue with site sites-available conf

Comment: are you 3 sites-available configuration using same the DocumentRoot statements point??

Comment: doc root path  is different